# Joins with Leagcy table with last letter s in name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have to write program for legacy tables in Polish language. Table is in polish and name of table finish with letter "s". Rails trying to cut "s" from name of table during joins in code :

```
@declarations = NfzDeclaration.aktywne.limit(100).joins(:nfz_decl_report_pos)
```

so I receive error :

```
"status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "#<NameError: uninitialized constant NfzDeclaration::NfzDeclReportPo>",
```

I can't change name of table - legacy database.

How I can said Rails to not cut "s" in join with table name *nfz_decl_report_pos* ?

Answer (score 0):

Using `table_table` should fix your problem:

```
class NfzDeclReportPos < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = ‘nfz_decl_report_pos’
end
```

If you want to use it only for joins, I think that you’ll have to write the SQL request without rails helpers

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it's declared this way from the begining :) So this is not solution for that. Yes I know that I can use pure SQL, but I'm looking for more Rails way ;) Anyway thanks for proposal.